# What does the <> operator do?

Tags: operators

I came across the <> operator in some C code and couldn't figure out for sure what it ment.
I'm guessing it's equal to != (not equal to) operator?

Could somebody please enlighten me?

Am i right to think that <> and != are the same or...?

EDIT:

Ow this is embarrassing :$ I was looking in an SQLite3 statement in C code. So what i ment was SQLite3 and not C :$ Sorry for the confusion..!

Comment: You need to post the actual line(s) of code containing this symbol.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, <> means NOT EQUAL TO.

Answer (score 13):

There is no `<>` operator in C.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Basic means Not equal but it does not exist in C!
in c you may have << or >> which are binary shift left and right respectivelly

Answer (score 2):

`C` has **Greater than** operator `>` and **Less than** operator `<`. It does not have any diamond operator `<>`. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++) for more reference on `C` operators.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, the `<>` operator indicates "Not Equal to" symbol but used in VB.net. I dont think this symbol is present in C language.

Comment: Not in C.  I suppose it's possible some C compiler supports it as an extension, but I've never heard of it.  (`<>` is the inequality operator in Pascal.)